# Need I put iOS Menu to UIView or UITableView?

Tags: ios7, interface-builder, xcode5

I want to create one static menu, and there are about 20 menu items, I think the UIView is easy for me, because I can put the menu item by drag the button as I want by InterfaceBuilder, But I found the overflow content is hidden, and the view can not be glided to bottom to show more items. I asked another question, someone suggest me use UITableView to solve this question, I am not sure which solution is better.

[image]

Comment: Of course you need tableView.

Comment: @malex But what cases does UIView user for ?

Answer (score 0):

UITableView is subclass of UIView to show scrollable collections of objects. It has data reuse mechanisms to save memory. You make NSArray of typical data and describe the UI of the UITableViewCell only once and then automatically reuse it while scrolling.

In case of UIView you need to define all objects even behind the bounds of visible frame and then implement UI interaction for scrolling by yourself. So pure UIView is good for compact set of different data enclosed by iPhone screen.